# logical-Volume / rhel 7

Tags: lvm, rhel7

How do I add 100% of the available free space from the volume group "centos" to the root logical volume?  What tool do I use to resize the root logical volume.

Below are the steps performed prior to this question.

```
root@server1 ~]# vgs

  VG     #PV  #LV #SN Attr Vsize Vfree

centos    1    2   0  wz--n- 6.98g 0

root@server1 ~]# pvcreate /dev/sdb

Physical volume "/dev/sdb" successfully created

root@server1 ~]# vgextend centos /dev/sdb

Volume group "centos" successfully created


root@server1 ~]# vgs


  VG     #PV  #LV #SN Attr Vsize Vfree

centos    2    2   0  wz--n- 7.46g 496.00m




root@server1 ~]# lvs

  LV     VG   Attr      LSize

 root   centos -wi-a0   6.18g

 swap   centos -wi-a0   820.00m
```

Answer (score 2):

You can issue `lvextend centos/root -l +100%FREE`, than you must use the appropriate filesystem resize utility tool. For example, if using XFS, you should issue `xfs_grow /`; on the other hand, if using EXT4, you should use `resize2fs /dev/centos/root`

Anyway, **before doing anything, TAKE BACKUPS**

Comment: I find adding  `--resizefs`  to my LVM resize operations convenient.  One command for the several file system types supported by `fsadm`.

Comment: "Thanks" for the suggestions but this seems to be differed from the predefined answers of a simulator  exercise I am trying to complete.
i have tried lvextend with FREE options, resizefs, xfs_grow but no luck

Comment: The same question can have multiple solution. Anyway, this site is not about asking about your homework/exercise. I'll vote to close.